# Why is NOT a protocol with a Turing-complete smart contract language able to use SNARKs to prove the validity of the chain?

Tags: zksnark, terminology, zero-knowledge, data-validity

In the following article (**Link to the article:** https://medium.com/nearprotocol/unsolved-problems-in-blockchain-sharding-2327d6517f43), the challenges of zk-SNARKs are mentioned as
follows:

> The challenges of zk-SNARKs, besides performance, are:
>
> - Dependency on less-researched and less-time-tested cryptographic primitives;
> - “Toxic waste” — zk-SNARKs depend on a trusted setup in which a group of people performs some computation and then discards the intermediate
>     values of that computation. If all the participants of the procedure
>     collude and keep the intermediate values, fake proofs can be created;
> - Extra complexity introduced into the system design;
> - zk-SNARKs only work for **a subset of possible computations**, so a **protocol with a Turing-complete smart contract** language **wouldn’t** be
>     able to use SNARKs **to prove the validity of the chain**.”

The questions are:

1. Why is **NOT** a protocol with a Turing-complete smart contract language able to use SNARKs to prove the validity of the chain?
2. What does it mean: *" zk-SNARKs only work for **a subset of possible computations** "*